# After updating to wordpress 4.4 can't install new plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

4 I tried installing a new plugin and got this error:

```
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/">support forums</a>. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 158
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 312
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 316
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:45 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: translations in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 323
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 312
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 316
[14-Dec-2015 18:36:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: translations in /var/www/html/wp-includes/update.php on line 323
```

I tried googling around and replaced update.php with the fresh one from a new wordpress download but it didn't help.

edit: replaced update.php with 4.3 and still got same error.  Did people replace all upgrade.php from 4.3 cause there are many different ones? anyone?

edit: still haven't solved it

Daily edit bump until someone else fixes my problem

Comment: Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration.. Did you wait some time and retry?

Comment: It seems a lot of people solved this issue by using the previous version of their upgrade.php. Did you tried to use the one from 4.3 instead?

Comment: No I didn't I will try that now

Comment: Do you mean upgrade.php or update.php?  Cause the error is about update.php